# NPOI 2.5.6 Page Breaks

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I have generated an xlsx file using NPOI(2.5.6) and I want to print it. I have took a look on the examples on github pages but none of the examples gave the result expected.

my goal is to print xlsx file without converting it to pdf then print it. can you provide me with step to step to print the sheet with landscape orientation with full width and height of the sheet. I can use other library they are applicable , my goal is just to not use Interop.

I have tried playing with these parameters but none of this gave the expected result :

```
 sheet.FitToPage = false;
 sheet.PrintSetup.Landscape = true;
 sheet.PrintSetup.PaperSize = (short)PaperSize.A4 + 1;
 sheet.PrintSetup.FitHeight = 9999;
 sheet.SetRowBreak(1000);
```